# AER pci error reporting in log files for R8169 network card

Tags: fedora, pci

I have a lot of errors in my kernel log on Fedora 39.  I have 4 NIC cards, and it reports for one only.  I tried to move it to another slot, but same issue.
Do you think it's something wrong with NIC card or maybe some conflict (IRQ)

```
Jan  8 10:33:14 z4 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1b.3: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan  8 10:33:14 z4 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1b.3: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan  8 10:33:14 z4 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan  8 10:33:14 z4 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0:   device [10ec:8168] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Jan  8 10:33:14 z4 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan  8 10:33:47 z4 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1b.3: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan  8 10:33:47 z4 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Transmitter ID)
Jan  8 10:33:47 z4 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0:   device [10ec:8168] error status/mask=00001001/00002000
Jan  8 10:33:47 z4 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan  8 10:33:47 z4 kernel: r8169 0000:04:00.0:    [12] Timeout
```

It consistently report errors for 1 NIC only.  I do also have 5 SATA drives and 1 NVME.  I didn't notice this errors, and I did upgrade to Fedora 39 and then I noticed.  I can provide some more output if needed.

```
#lspci |grep Ethernet
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
```

I've seen some similar posts about other devices, but most answers revolve around disabling pciereporting, which isn't a solution.  (adding to the grub pci=nomsi and pci=noaer)

Comment: Try either `pcie_aspm=off` or `pci=noaer` or `pci=nomsi` as your boot flag.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov but that just suppresses errors reporting?  I'd like to find out if I need new NIC card or is there some IRQ conflict or something else.  And is not so easy to just replace NIC, as ISP has to make a new DHCP reservation when card replaced, so I can't just play back and forth

Answer (score 1):

These are *corrected* errors. So, not inherently a problem. Yeah, sure, it's not great that they happen, but under heavy load, it's almost sure that bit errors happen, and the fact that your system corrects them is appropriate and means nothing broke.

So, Artem's recommendation of just disabling logging of these if they are annoying to you is reasonable. I'd instead just recommend ignoring them. It's not like you can do anything about the signal quality of on-board PCIe traces  of your motherboard or the quality of the bus driving logic and buffers in a piece of silicon.

Comment: Thanks @Marcus. So do you think it's just signal issue, and not some hardware problem with the network card or some resource conflict on the motherboard or something else?  I've noticed that when I reboot server now it would not be able to activate this card, so I have to do another reboot, and than it works again.  I have latest 6.6.9 kernel, so software wise all should be OK, but this NIC has been in the machine 10+ years.

Comment: re what I think it is: written in my answer already!